# C# and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, postgresql, ado.net

Can anyone show me a working example of using a cursor returned from PLSQL to C# code?

I found many examples showing how to fill a `dataSet` with returned data, but I cannot find how to use that cursor with a `DataReader`, so as a result I have `{unnamed portal}`.

```
NpgsqlTransaction tr = (NpgsqlTransaction) Connection.BeginTransaction();
NpgsqlCommand cursCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("someStoredProcedure(:inRadius)", (NpgsqlConnection) Connection);
cursCmd.Transaction = tr;
NpgsqlParameter rf = new NpgsqlParameter("ref", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
rf.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cursCmd.Parameters.Add(rf);
```

I have to add this to use `NpgsqlDataReader myReader;` correctly:

```
tr.Commit();
```

When I wrote `fetch` after the sql command, it works but it is not suitable.

Comment: I think it is rather specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got some answers on my question.

Problem: I have a stored PLSQL procedure which returns `refCursor`. I have to get the returned data with a `DataReader`, but wwhen I added parameters, the db returned `<unnamed portal>`.

To walk through all returned data I have to write my code like so:

```
NpgsqlTransaction tr = (NpgsqlTransaction) Connection.BeginTransaction();
NpgsqlCommand cursCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("someStoredProcedure", (NpgsqlConnection) Connection);
cursCmd.Transaction = tr;
NpgsqlParameter rf = new NpgsqlParameter("ref", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
rf.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
cursCmd.Parameters.Add(rf);

NpgsqlParameter param2 = new NpgsqlParameter("param1", NpgsqlTypes.Int32);
rf.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cursCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
NpgsqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (r.Read())
{
    ; // r.GetValue(0);
}
r.NextResult();
while(r.Read())
{
    ;
}

tr.Commit();
```

Notice that you don't write your parameters in sql like `func(:param1)`.

If you have parameters in your function, assign only the function name to the `CommandText` property and add parameters to the `NpgsqlCommand.Parameters` collection as usual. Npgsql will take care of binding your parameters correctly.

But now I have another problem. When I pass another output parameter to my `CommandText`, I have two fields in my result. One of them is `0{my first output param}` and the other is `<unnamed portal>`.

In Oracle, I can directly convert a `RefCursor` parameter to a `DataReader`, but in postgresql, I cannot.

Answer (score 4):

For your reference:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get data from the returning refcursor of postgresql function
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FunctionName">Function name of postgresql</param>
/// <param name="Parameters">parameters to pass to the postgresql function</param>
/// <param name="ErrorOccured">out bool parameter to check if it occured error</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<DataTable> GetRefCursorData(string FunctionName, List<object> Parameters, out bool ErrorOccured)
{ 
    string connectstring = ""; //your connectstring here
    List<DataTable >  dtRtn =new List<DataTable>();
    NpgsqlConnection connection = null;
    NpgsqlTransaction transaction = null;
    NpgsqlCommand command = null;            
    try
    {
        connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectstring);
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        command = new NpgsqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = FunctionName;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        //
        if (Parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (object item in Parameters)
            {
                NpgsqlParameter parameter = new NpgsqlParameter();
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter.Value = item;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
        }
        //
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            command = new NpgsqlCommand("FETCH ALL IN " + "\"" + dr[0].ToString() + "\"", Connection); //use plpgsql fetch command to get data back
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dtRtn.Add(dt); //all the data will save in the List<DataTable> ,no matter the connection is closed or returned multiple refcursors
        }                
        ErrorOccured = false;
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    { 
        //error handling ...
        ErrorOccured = true;
        if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null) connection.Close();
    }
    return dtRtn;
}
```

Comment: This answer will be more useful when you provide a sample call of your function. For example, how should we initialize List<object> Parameters?

Comment: There is error "A command is already in progress:" on this line execution 
da.Fill(dt);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is some documentation that could be useful: [Npgsql doc](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)

In this documentation you'll find a `NpgsqlDataAdapter`. This object also has a `Fill()` method (inherited from `DbDataAdapter`). This method can take a `DataSet` and a cursor. It will **fill** the `DataSet` with the data returned by your cursor.

You can't actually give a `DataReader` to this method, but you can give a `DataTable`, I think you can manage to do something with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with `Out` parameters by using two commands in the same transaction.

In the first command, I read the out parameter and then execute the next command.

The second command looks like:

```
var cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand("FETCH ALL FROM \"list\"", (NpgsqlConnection) Connection)
```

Where `list` the name of cursor created inside the stored procedure. As a result I get data selected from the db.