# C# and PlSql Cursor

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql

I have a Pl/Sql procedure signature that look like this

`foo(param1 IN type1, param2 IN type1, c OUT REF CURSOR)`.

This stored procedure is being called in C#. In the C# code, I fill a DataTable with this cursor. I would like to know when the cursor will be closed.

Should I close it in the SP? In the code? Or is the object OracleRefCursor will close it when I'll call the Dispose method(cause it has no Close method)?

Thanks

Edit : Here is some example of the code I'm using

Stored proc :

```
create or replace procedure foo1(param1 IN type1, param2 IN type1, c OUT REF CURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN c
    FOR
       SELECT x
       FROM table;
END;

create or replace procedure foo2(param3 IN type1, param4 IN type1, c OUT REF CURSOR)
IS
   temp type1 := param3;
   x type1;
BEGIN
   LOOP temp < param4
      foo1(temp, param4, c);
      FETCH c INTO x;
      temp := temp +1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have some example of working with c# and plsql cursor?
because i have posted question recently nobody answered

Comment: Can you show me some c# sample? Because I have problem with reading from Cursor with DataReader. There ara many examples with DataAdapter but none with DataReader. Thanx in advance.

Comment: I'm using a DataAdapter.Fill() method to fill a DataTable with the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not close cursor because no data will be returned, you have to close it in your c# code.

Comment: But how? I use a OracleRefCursor object to store the cursor but there is no such ting as a close method on this object. Only a dipose().

Comment: view my topic there are some explorations about it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037000/c-and-postgresql